# TYPO3 v12 / flux:form.container does not work

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-12.x

Didn't use an flux:form.container for some month now, but on the latest v12 version it's broken.

I used it as always:

```
<flux:form id="testimonial" options="{group:'rxgrid',icon:'EXT:herzog/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/Testimonial.svg',Fluidcontent:{hidden: 1}}">
   <flux:form.container name="settings.testimonial" label="Testimonial">
      <flux:field.text label="Text" name="text" enableRichText="true" richtextConfiguration="rxminimal-h3-link"/>
      <flux:field.input name="name" label="Name"/>
   </flux:form.container>
</flux:form>
```

It now throws an exception when editinng that content element:
[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HUkD.png)

I'm on TYPO3 12.4.8 with Flux 10.0.7.
Any suggestions?